# How to use server_name in Nginx under HTTP/2?

Tags: nginx, http2

I want to use 2 server blocks.
The first is:

```
    server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 fastopen=3 reuseport;
    server_name a.example.xyz;
    include server_safe.conf;
    root /home/www/blog/;
    }
```

The second is:

```
  server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name b.example.xyz;
    include server_safe.conf;
}
```

What I want:
I want the server_name to be valid, that is , if I use a `c.example.xyz` to visit my website, both `a.example.xyz`,`b.example.xyz`,`c.example.xyz` is the same IP , the server should block the `c.example.xyz` request because it is not in the `server_name`.

However, if I enter `https://c.example.xyz`, the Nginx will still receive the request and reponse as `a.example.xyz`

I know HTTP/2 has no host in its header, it has a `:authority` instead.

My question is that : How can I reject any other request? I only want to accept the request under(with) the `host(:authority)` = `a(b).example.xyz`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the first Server block is used by default if no other name matches.

Therefore to achieve what you want, you need to create a default block, **before** the other two, and have it block or redirect, or show an error page.

The downsides of this are:

1. Unless you have HTTPS certificates that all the domain names (or use a wildcard cert that covers this), then they will get an error when going to https version of your site and use this default config. Though this would happen under your current set up anyway. There is no way AFAIK to send a block message **before** the HTTPS negotiation happens.
2. Older clients that don't support SNI (primarily Windows XP) will go to default config, whereas previously they would have gotten through for Server A as it was the default (though not for server B).

The alternative is to write a redirect rule based on the hostname provided. Not 100% sure how to do this on nginx to be honest but if not possible by default then is possible with ModSecurity. Again it will only take effect **after** the HTTPS negotiation has happened so still leaves you with a potential incorrect cert problem.

Comment: You are correct, according to your answer , I created a new server block with `server_name _` before other server block, so that any other request can be given a 404. Of course , since it get a response of 404, it has gone through the https negotiation. My cert has SAN, my nginx has SNI, so cert is not a problem.  At last , thanks a lot